# Parse migration error, and now?

Tags: parse-platform, migration

I was migrating my app in Parse.com to Heroku+mongolab, but at the end something happend and now all I see is this:

[image: Parse migration error]

Do you know what to do then? Who can I contact?

Thanks

#### Edit 1

So, I clicked on App Settings > General and this is what appears:

[image]

If the button Migrate is red, does it mean that there is no problem? I ask this because I have seen other questions related (https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/parse-developers/tPLTxNUf8Uo) where this button appears blue with the text "View Progress"

Comment: Not sure what the problem is, but I have a couple test apps that have never been migrated, and the Migrate button is red.  That's the normal color, I think.  You should definitely run through first with a test app.  Also, I think this question probably belongs elsewhere on stack exchange.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure when you were creating a User in mongolab for your database is not being marked as  ""MAKE READ-ONLY"

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UIXhd.png)